# LaTeX commands in pgfplots legend entries from csv import

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv, import

I am trying to import data from a csv file, where legend entries are automatically taken from the csv file's header. Those legend entries contain LaTeX math code.

```tex
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
        ,Distance ($\mathrm{ABC}=\SI{1}{\second}$),Velocity,Something
        0,0,1,0.2
        1,1,1,0.3
        1.5,1.999,1,0.4
        2,2,0,0.4
        3,2,0,0.5
    \end{filecontents}
    \newcommand{\plotfile}[1]{
        \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{#1}{\table}
        \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
            \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
            \addplot table [y index=##1] {\table};
            \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \plotfile{testdata.dat}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...
                                     #4  \errhelp \@err@    ...
l.525       \plotfile{testdata.dat}
                                   ^^M
```

When I remove the LaTeX commands from the csv (I can keep the math dollar signs) and try to set the legend manually with `\legend{Distance ($\mathrm{ABC}=\SI{1}{\second}$), Velocity, Something}`, it works.

How can I import column names / legend entries including LaTeX commands from a csv?